# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape' when using reshape for a list

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, reshape

according to my code, i want to read the frames and convert them to array. after that using the np.array according below:

```
img = Image.open(os.path.join(source_folder, item))
        frames.append(item)
        x.append(np.asarray(img))
        w.append(np.array(x[i]))
```

when i run the bellow cell

```
w_train, w_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(w, y, test_size=0.2 ,shuffle=True, random_state=42)

w_train = w_train.reshape(2404,28,224,224,3)
w_test = w_test.reshape(601,28,224,224,3)
```

i face with this error for w_train when i want to use reshape:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-809eb2542c50> in <module>
      
----> 9 w_train = w_train.reshape(2404,28,224,224,3)
     10 w_test = w_test.reshape(601,28,224,224,3)
     

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

Comment: np.array(w_train).reshape(2404, 28, 224, 224, 3) ?

Comment: the shape of w_train is (67312,224,224,2). i want to reshape it to (2404,28,224,224,3). how can i?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your list to a numpy array and then reshape it with `numpy.reshape`

```
import numpy as np

# Convert to numpy array
w_train = np.array(w_train)
w_test = np.array(w_train)

# Reshape
w_train = np.reshape(w_train, (2404,28,224,224,3))
w_test = np.reshape(w_test, (601,28,224,224,3))
```

Comment: it works for right now. but when i use more number of frames for instance w_train.shape is = (266448,224,224,3), when i using w_train = np.array(w_train) i face with this error: 
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

how can i solve the problem for big number of frames?

Comment: @mohamad that error did not happen on `w_train = np.array(w_train)`. That happened on some other line and therefore is another problem. Start another question on it with the relevant code.

Answer (score -1):

**reshape** is a methode under **numpy**'s library and as the error printed in your terminal the object **list** has **no methode** defined as reshape

```
import numpy as np 
w_train=np.array(x_train)
```

then you can simply use the reshape function without any error :

```
w_train=x_train.reshape((2404,28,224,224,3))
```

you can check the reshape characteristics in this [**link**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reshape-numpy-array/) for more understanding of the methode

Comment: it works for right now. but when i use more number of frames for instance w_train.shape is = (333060,224,224,3), when i using w_train = np.array(w_train) i face with this error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. how can i solve the problem for big number of frames?

Comment: @mohamad can  you please show me the format of **w** because the problem may be  you are trying to create an array from a list that isn't shaped like a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: w.dtype is 'object'. i don't know what happening

Comment: check the shape of w_train an w_test in the beginning maybe you're trying to reduce one of those shapes